# Fail / Pass a check-in

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a requirement : When ever a developer checks-in some code in TFS,
Before committing, a log file in a pre-defined path should be checked. If the file says pass, only then that particular check-in should be committed, else it should be failed.

How can I implement this? Since I am new to TFS, any inputs would help me a lot.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Where will this log file be located? On the build machine or on the developer's workstation?

Comment: @john The file is located on build server.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a Gated check in.
You will then need to add a custom task to read back the file.
If the value is not found in the file then you can fail the build, which will stop the code from being committed to source control